# I have an idea for a new kind of LEGO, using new types of elements

Tags: ideas

I have an idea for a new LEGO product (not a LEGO set or anything, I know that the Lego ideas site exists, but a new "kind" of LEGO)

I've been trying to contact LEGO about it without any luck.

So I thought I'd give this site a shot as well since I think the idea has a lot of potential.

Now to the question. Is there any way I can contact a LEGO designer or just anyone at LEGO to pitch my idea to?
Or should I just give up?

Comment: We already have some pointers for [contacting a designer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2767/56) and it's been pointed out that [LEGO don't really take suggestions](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/4591/56) for new products other than through Ideas.

Comment: Re-opened as the duplicate suggestion recommends using ideas, and Oskar's aware of that and that's it's not really appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is a new kind of part, element in plastic, you may want to take it into your own hands and try to design it in a free cad app (like Sketchup, Open SCAD, Creo Elements or something). There are people around here (like myself) who have 3d printers, and may be able to suggest or try things out. You can then see if there is a market for such Lego compatible elements - see who else is interested.

Lego are unlikely to take these kind of risks themselves, but there are resources for people to try new things themselves.

Comment: This.  You almost never will get traction with a major corporation about adopting your (significant) ideas (because, among other reasons, they'd have to pay you for them - even if you don't want payment); but there's nothing special about 'plastic blocks' such that you couldn't make your own competing (and, more importantly, compatible) product, and then perhaps eventually Lego will see your idea and either make their own, or buy your idea/company.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure which direction you're going in for the "new 'kind' of LEGO - but as you point out, unless this is based around existing LEGO elements [Ideas is probably not for you](https://ideas.lego.com/guidelines#anchor-34):

> **Your models may only use existing LEGO parts. We do not allow suggestions for new LEGO parts.**

So unless it's based on System (and by extension Friends and Elves) or DUPLO you're probably out of luck there - from an older [Cusoo FAQ](http://blog.lego.cuusoo.com/2012/05/29/cheat-sheet-how-to-pass-the-lego-review-with/):

> Models should not depend on new LEGO element molds. While we love considering new elements, if a model depends on a new element, there are more potential factors on which it can fail review. [...] An existing element in a new color is OK, but a new element in one set isn’t likely.

You might get some traction through the [Marketing teams](http://www.lego.com/en-gb/aboutus/lego-group/media_contacts), as product development comes under the "Marketing and Products" division under the CMO - for example the 2011 edition of "The LEGO Group - a short presentation" talks about there being a number of "product development deparments", while the 2014 edition shows "product group 1" and "product group 2" and both state that:

> Concept and product development takes place primarily at our Billund headquarters in Denmark. The LEGO Group also has a listening post in Los Angeles to help monitor the
>   latest trends.